# Difference between require VS empty object ({}) on plugin definitions PostCSS config JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, postcss

Somewhat of a straightforward question that doesn't seem to have very clear answer in the [PostCSS docs](https://postcss.org/api/#processor-plugins). I noticed that in the [PostCSS Usage Guide](https://github.com/postcss/postcss#usage) they define the `postcss.config.js` file plugins using require statements like so:

```js
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('precss'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

However, other PostCSS examples such as from the [PostCSS CLI docs](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli#context) explaining the function form of `postcss.config.js`, they use a different syntax for plugins

```
module.exports = (ctx) => ({
  map: ctx.options.map,
  parser: ctx.options.parser,
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': { root: ctx.file.dirname },
    cssnano: ctx.env === 'production' ? {} : false,
  },
})
```

And there are [other online tutorials](https://www.toptal.com/react/webpack-config-tutorial-pt-2) as well following this syntax

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    "postcss-preset-env": {}
  }
};
```

**I guess my question is....**
Why are plugins defined using an array of `require('<name>')` in one place, and using a keyed object using empty objects as values `{}` in another? Are there any functional differences? Is one better than the other?

Comment: Stumbled here with the same question. I think it's just that when you define it as an object, you can pass in config options right there which is arguably prettier with no functional difference. But I'm also not a 100% sure.

Comment: That's not it. You can pass config options with require() syntax as well as object syntax, ex: `require('postcss-nested')({ preserveEmpty: true })` see https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested#options

Answer (score 1):

### it's old and new syntax

(for backward compatibility works both)

Recommended is the string one, with options in the brackets.

For example [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config) says:

> Do **not use `require()`** to import the PostCSS Plugins. Plugins must be provided as strings.

Comment: The Next.js source recommending string syntax is great! But nothing in the official PostCSS docs explains why string syntax is recommended over require() In fact, the official examples on the PostCSS github use require() instead of the string import: https://github.com/postcss/postcss#usage

String syntax is definitely cleaner, but require() seems way more explicit. So IDK why one would be old/new syntax.